# Unreachable code in the Eclipse editor

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse

I have a problem with this code, it says "Unreachable code".
It says that the

```
EntityLivingBase entity = (EntityLivingBase) theObject;
```

is a unreachable code.
Here's my code:

```
@Override
public void onRender() {

    if (!this.isToggled())
        return;

    for(Object theObject : mc.theWorld.loadedEntityList) {
        if(!(theObject instanceof EntityLivingBase)) {
            continue;

            EntityLivingBase entity = (EntityLivingBase) theObject;

            if(entity instanceof EntityPlayer) {
                if(entity != mc.thePlayer)
                    player(entity);
                continue;
            }

            if (entity instanceof EntityMob) {
                mob(entity);
                continue;
            }

            if (entity instanceof EntityAnimal) {
                animal(entity);
                continue;
            }

            passive(entity);
        }
    }
super.onRender();
}
```

Comment: You can remove all of those continue statements and your logic is wrong in the initial if statement, I suspect. `!(theObject instanceof EntityLivingBase)` should be `theObject instanceof EntityLivingBase`, as you then cast it to that immediately afterwards. And don't call it `theObject`. Call it something more meaningful than that :)

Comment: Thank, you this worked out for me!
Now it's working.
~I'm not really expierenced with Java script, I'm still learning.
Thank you!

Comment: @LiamYS Please learn the difference between [tag:java] and [tag:javascript] (apart from similar names and algol-like syntax, they are **very** different).

Answer (score 0):

With `continue` you are ending the iteration at that point. The rest of the code is unreachable because it will be never processed.

Comment: So I need to remove the continue; ?

Answer (score 0):

The `continue` keyword makes Java skip the rest of the code and then re-iterate for the next element in the for loop. What your code does is skip to the next iteration before the rest of the code in the for loop has had time to run. I don't really know why you have put it there, maybe a misunderstanding of its use?

Answer (score 0):

What others have said is correct. The `continue` always skips the rest of the code, which becomes useless as it can never be reached, and hence you get the unreachable statement error.

I think that this is a typo error, and If I understand it correctly, the code should be:

```
if(!(theObject instanceof EntityLivingBase)) {
        continue;
} // This is missing.
```

The rest of the code should be after you close the `if` block.